# Could not open macro storage

Tags: vba, ms-word

Im getting

> could not open macro storage error

in vba whenever my code tries to open msword document.

I even tried creating a new word document but the issue still persists

What i've looked at

1. changing file block settings in word
2. unblocking the file (theres no unblock option in my word properties so didnt try)

[image]

Comment: SO requires that you post the actual code, not an image.  You'll also need to show us how the entity that is passed as wordpath is declared and assigned.  Please also remove On error statements from code that is in development unless they OE is scoped in a Try function or similar.

Comment: If your macro is running in Word there's no need to create another instance of Word to open a document.

Comment: Do you try to automate Word from Excel VBA macro? Do you get the same error when you open the Word file manually?

Comment: This was run from Excel VBA. and i dont get this error when opening the word manually

Answer (score 0):

If you run the VBA macro in Word there is no need to create a new Word instance and open the document there:

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Instead, you can use the `Application` property available in VBA.